# Corona SDK: Is it posible to work with image and save changes?

Tags: image, coronasdk

Is it possible to work with an image in Corona SDK and then save to file?

Namely:

1. Open an image file
2. Create polygon on the image and fill with color
3. Save all as new image file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is [`display.save()`](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/save.html)

Create a display group with the image and the polygon and then save it.